# Springdoc-openapi external json file with relative path for example request body

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am looking for a way to use a relative path for external JSON files while defining the example request body.

My current definition is like this:

```
@Operation(requestBody = @RequestBody(description = "Request", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Request.class), examples = {
            @ExampleObject(
                    name = "An example request",
                    value = "{\n" +
                               "\"token\":\"token\"\n" +
                            "}",
                    summary = "Request"
            )}
)),summary = "summ", description = "desc")
```

I want to keep JSON value on an external JSON file.

I know that "externalValue" field can be used instead of "value" to reference an external json file, but it requires a URL. I want to keep it in the project file and use the relative path. I am using Open API v3.

For those who are just looking for external JSON file usage, you can use external JSON file from a URL like this:

```
@Operation(requestBody = @RequestBody(description = "Request", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Request.class), examples = {
        @ExampleObject(
                name = "An example request",
                externalValue = "http://domain/test/example.json",
                summary = "Request"
        )}
)),summary = "summ", description = "desc")
```

Comment: Is there any way to add the resources file content to the `@ExampleObject`? I am trying to add the `@ExampleObject` from the `resources file` using `ref` but its not working for some reason. I have posted my question:  stackoverflow.com/q/71616547/7584240

Comment: If you have a chance to keep sample json objects in public storage, you can use the externalValue field. You just need to provide url of that json file. You can see the example usage.

Comment: Did you find what you want? Can you share?

Comment: @JinKwon I uploaded json to our internal system and used its URL with externalValue field. In that way only people who have access to the internal system can see json in that way, that partially solved my problem.